Cannot borrow `scene` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
I am making an ECS game engine, using this as a base https://ianjk.com/ecs-in-rust/.
Each scene has a map with
pub struct Scene {
    pub entities_index: usize,
    pub component_map: HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn ComponentVec>>,
}

Components can be base struct like this
pub struct TransformComponent {
    pub transform: Mat4,
    children: Vec<usize>,
}

Or a trait object
pub trait Controller{
    fn update(&mut self, index: usize, scene: &mut Scene);
}

Getting the dynamic components is working fine using generics like the following:
pub fn borrow_component_vec_mut<ComponentType: 'static>(
        &self,
    ) -> Option<RefMut<Vec<Option<ComponentType>>>> {
        if let Some(component_vec) = self.component_map.get(&TypeId::of::<ComponentType>()) {
        if let Some(component_vec) = component_vec
            .as_any()
            .downcast_ref::<RefCell<Vec<Option<ComponentType>>>>()
        {
            return Some(component_vec.borrow_mut());
        }
    }
    None
}

But I would like the controller component trait to have access to its index and the scene mutably when the frame is drawn so it can for example grab another of its components and mutate it.
The problem arises when I get a mutable Controller component and try to pass in a &mut Scene to its update function
let mut scene = self.scenes[0].write().unwrap();
let mut controllers: std::cell::RefMut<'_, Vec<Option<Box<dyn Controller>>>> = scene.borrow_component_vec_mut::<Box<dyn Controller>>().unwrap();
for (index, mut controller) in controllers.iter_mut().enumerate() {
    if let Some(controller) = controller.as_mut(){
        controller.update(index, &mut scene);
    }
}
drop(controllers);
drop(scene);

So I get why this won't work because borrow_component_vec_mut takes a immutable reference to Scene as &self and I already have a mutable reference to Scene in the same scope, but I drop the controllers and scene after and won't be used later apart from dropping.
I can't borrow immutably Controllers because they have state to mutate, I can't send Scene as <Arc<RwLock> as it just blocks when write lock is called. How should I go about solving this?
Edit: I got this to work by following suggestions by @Jmb and @Finn Bear. Basically wrap the controller as Arc<Mutex<Box>>. As well not mutating in the loop. It seems like overkill - is there a more elegant solution?
let mut scene = self.scenes[0].write().unwrap();
let mut test = vec![];
let mut controllers = scene.borrow_component_vec_mut::<Arc<Mutex<Box<dyn Controller>>>>().unwrap();
for (index, controller) in controllers.iter().enumerate() {
    if let Some(controller) = controller {
        test.push((index, controller.clone()));
    }
}
drop(controllers);
drop(scene);
for (index, mut controller) in test {
    let mut controller = controller.lock().unwrap();
    controller.update(index, self.scenes[0].clone());
}


If a component has mutable access to scene, then it could change its controllers vec through the scene's component_map. But you're currently iterating the controllers vec…

"have access to its index" -> pass the usize rather than the whole scene. "grab another of its components and mutate" -> the nightly get_many_mut might be relevant, but also consider putting each individual component in a Mutex. Then the code could compile with immutable references, but locking the same component twice = deadlock/panic/etc.

@Jmb Yes I know that is an issue, I was asking how I could design it better.

@FinnBear I would be happy passing in an Arc<RwLock> but I tried it and I kind of need to queue up the updates then drop the scene from the calling method so it doesn't try to lock up, then have the updates execute does this make sense?

I got it to work by using @FinnBears suggestion
